# Query Data in ArcOnline REST API. Set-up error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, .net, arcgis-rest-api

I am attempting to query data that has been loaded into ArcGIS in the form of layers.

I am attempting to query out basic data (Any data at this point) from a imported Layer.  I think the error is with my .Net code and how I set up to attempt the query but I seem to run into errors when I attempt to query data that is present in the tutorial.

Code Below:

```
        public async static Task QuerySantaAnaData()
    {
        string tokenString = ""; //This is generated on the the Dashboard for ArcGIS for Developers page under Temporay Access Token

        string path = @"https://services3.arcgis.com/{My ID}/ArcGIS/rest/services/{Service Name}/FeatureServer/0/query?where=FID>0&outFields=*";
        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0, 0);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Token", tokenString);

                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path))
                {
                    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                    {
                        string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The Inner Exception I receive is

```
{System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)}
```

I have even attempted to perform this API request with the example data that ArcGIS provides in their tutorials here https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/rest/query-a-feature-layer/

Answer (score 1):

Try sending your token in the URL query params (`string path = @"https://services3.arcgis.com/{My ID}/ArcGIS/rest/services/{Service Name}/FeatureServer/0/query?where=FID>0&outFields=*&token=______";`) instead of in the headers.